# django-profile passing variables to template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-profiles

Django newbie at work and I could use some pointers. I'm using django-profile and have been working on my profile page which is handled by the views.profile_detail. The problem I am facing is I am unable to put another variable in my template by using this view. Here is my view function:

```
def profile_detail(request, username, public_profile_field=None,
               template_name='profiles/profile_detail.html',
               extra_context=None):
"""
Detail view of a user's profile.

If no profile model has been specified in the
``AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`` setting,
``django.contrib.auth.models.SiteProfileNotAvailable`` will be
raised.

If the user has not yet created a profile, ``Http404`` will be
raised.

**Required arguments:**

``username``
    The username of the user whose profile is being displayed.

**Optional arguments:**

``extra_context``
    A dictionary of variables to add to the template context. Any
    callable object in this dictionary will be called to produce
    the end result which appears in the context.

``public_profile_field``
    The name of a ``BooleanField`` on the profile model; if the
    value of that field on the user's profile is ``False``, the
    ``profile`` variable in the template will be ``None``. Use
    this feature to allow users to mark their profiles as not
    being publicly viewable.

    If this argument is not specified, it will be assumed that all
    users' profiles are publicly viewable.

``template_name``
    The name of the template to use for displaying the profile. If
    not specified, this will default to
    :template:`profiles/profile_detail.html`.

**Context:**

``profile``
    The user's profile, or ``None`` if the user's profile is not
    publicly viewable (see the description of
    ``public_profile_field`` above).

**Template:**

``template_name`` keyword argument or
:template:`profiles/profile_detail.html`.

"""
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
# accuracy = ''
try:
    profile_obj = user.get_profile()
    accuracy = str(profile_obj.number_of_answers / profile_obj.number_of_answers) + '%'
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
if public_profile_field is not None and \
   not getattr(profile_obj, public_profile_field):
    profile_obj = None

if extra_context is None:
    # extra_context = {'accuracy': potato}
    extra_context = {}
context = RequestContext(request)
# context['accuracy'] = 'potato'
for key, value in extra_context.items():
    context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value

return render_to_response(template_name,
                          {'profile': profile_obj},
                          # { 'profile': profile_obj, 'accuracy': accuracy},
                          # locals(),
                          context_instance=context)
```

and here is my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<p><strong>Level:</strong><br>{{ profile.level }}</p>
<p><strong>Bounty Points:</strong><br>{{ profile.total_bounty_points }}</p>
<p><strong>Number of questions:</strong><br>{{ profile.number_of_questions_asked }}</p>
<p><strong>Number of replies:</strong><br>{{ profile.number_of_replies }}</p>
<p><strong>Number of answers:</strong><br>{{ profile.number_of_answers }}</p>
<p><strong>Accuracy:</strong><br>{{ accuracy }}</p>
<p><strong>Number of times reported:</strong><br>{{ profile.reported_by_others }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

May I know where the value profile is being passed from? Is it from the dictionary {'profile': profile_obj} or is it from the context? I tried commenting out both but the template still renders fine.

I have also tried to create a new variable called accuracy in my template but I am unable to get it to render and the template simply fails silently. I then added     TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = '%s' to my settings file which allowed me to see that the accuracy variable is not found. May I know what I did wrong?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If this is the view from the third-party application, you shouldn't be modifying it yourself - the whole point of the `extra_context` argument is that you can pass in extra values from the urlconf, which is how you would pass whatever `accuracy` is supposed to be.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the comment and I totally understand what you mean :) I tried this     url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$',
                           views.profile_detail, extra_context={'accuracy': 'potato'}, name='profiles_profile_detail'), Does this mean I should be able to use the variable {{ accuracy }} directly, because it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh I found the problem! I was changing the wrong file >_< as my python install had written to the default directory.